# Determine if a curve is an elliptic curve given characteristic 2 and 3?

Tags: analysis, field-theory, elliptic-curves, modular-forms

Given $E:$ $y^2 = x^3 + a$, $a$ being an element of the field $K$, determine if $E$ if an elliptic curve if:

1. The characteristic of $K$ is not 2 or 3
2. The characteristic of $K$ is 2
3. The characteristic of $K$ is 3

I know definition of a [characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_(algebra)) but as a beginner in the introduction to elliptic curves I do not understand how characteristic apply to the algebraic equation of the type $E$ above.

I know if $char(K) = 2$, then $2=0$ but I don't know where to go from here.
I also know that a curve is elliptic if the partial derivatives are not simultaneously null but Im failing to understand where the characteristic plays part.

Comment: Well, the partial derivatives being $0$ or not depends strongly on whether $2=0$ or $3=0$, (or neither)!

Comment: Okay in the text I'm revising with they also state, if $char(K)=2$, $(0, a^{1/2})$ is a singular point, hence $E$ is not an elliptic curve. Are they merely substituting $x=0$ when $3=0$?

Comment: The partial derivatives are $-3x^2$ and $2y$. If the characteristic is $2$, then $2y = 0$ for all $y$. Thus every point on $E$ with $x$-coordinate $0$ will be a singular point. As you say, substituting $x = 0$ into the equation, the corresponding $y$-values are $\pm \sqrt{a}$. One can proceed similarly when the characteristic is $3$, as well.

Comment: Well, $E$ is nonsingular if and only if the discriminant does not vanish. The discriminant in this case should be $-16 \cdot 27 \cdot a^2$, so....